# Dream company or dream work place?

Tags: business-language

How can I call companies that I would really like to work in (and let's say no matter how badly people are talking about them)? 
'List of my dream companies' or 'List of my dream work places'? Or maybe there is another name for such situation. Thanks!

-- Edit taken from comment --

This expression would be used publicly (in a website), so our goal is to understand it as something which refers to companies they would like to work at.

Comment: Both of those phrases are correct in English and understandable. I prefer the first but that is simply a matter of opinion.

Comment: I think they're different - you could like to work for Company A no matter what the work place was like, or you could want to work for a company with a strong social workplace, or one without one.

Comment: Maybe "dream employer" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: Or "favourite companies".

Answer (score 2):

To me, *dream work place* (or [*workplace*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workplace)) refers more to the immediate environment in which the employees work.  So, it more naturally refers to things like the social atmosphere between employees (things like trust and teamwork), the physical comfort of the environment, and amenities such as free drinks or food.  There are companies out there that attempt to nail this concept down; see [What is a Great Workplace?](http://www.greatplacetowork.net/our-approach/what-is-a-great-workplace).

*Dream company* can also include such things, but by using the word "company" it emphasizes the corporate entity.  Thus, it might be seen to more naturally include things like opportunities for career advancement, quality/responsiveness of upper management, and strong growth potential.

Some key aspects of employment, like salary and having a good boss, are included in both.

Comment: I agree with you and @PressTilty (in a comment) that there's a difference between 'company' and 'workplace.' Another option for expressing the 'dream company' notion (but not necessarily the 'dream workplace' one) could be "Dream employer."  "Dream employee...have guts, will travel [for the right dream employer]!"

Answer (score 0):

I should call it *a list of companies I dream to work for* (or *work at*), but you may call the list what you like, after all it is your list. You are naming it. :)

Strictly, without further context "Dream company" and "dream work place" may be considered ambiguous: A company might be your "dream company" or "dream work place" for many other reasons, than you wanting to work there, but I shouldn't worry. I don't imagine your use case involves much third party scrutiny, and thus I recommend naming it something that feels right to you. Such a list is a highly personal thing, anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But this expression would be used publicly (in a website), so our goal is to understand it as something which refers to companies they would like to work at.

Comment: Then I should use the sentence mentioned in my first paragraph. Use "work for" or "work at" as you please. The difference between the two: When working for a company, the focus is on the service you provide to the company (also you might be merely employed by a subcontractor). When working at a company, the focus is on the place of employment (also you are definitely employed by the main company). If it is for use with applicants I would choose "for" to encourage a work ethic of service.

Answer (score 0):

`Dream company` works fine and keeps it focused on the employer.

`Dream job` is what I seem to hear more often though it suggests not just the employer but other stuff like pay, perks, workplace, and duties.

The problem is that `dream` is a bit close to `fantasy` and may connote things like `daydreaming` and `not paying attention`

Perhaps `goal company` or `goal job` is better because then you can keep it focused on something concrete and achievable that you want to work toward by setting `objectives`.